# Can I use these letters of reference later?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, career-path, recommendation-letter, bachelor

I was working with some startups as their tech advisory and with some others as tech lead. But now I want to concentrate on my main goal, that is research. That requires me to work with researchers and study. So I asked people I was working with, for a recommendation letter. As I am aiming towards Waterloo for my masters for research. The real problem is I was not so much focused on my academics as I was busy here. Though I still have last two years to cover up at Waterloo, usually checks last two year scores. I just want to know will these LORs will help me, when I will apply, in Waterloo, after my engineering and giving my GRE.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that if you want letters that won't become relevant for a few years, that you tell the writers that so that they might be able to update their recommendations at the appropriate time, without forgetting you. Keeping in touch is also useful for that.

I don't know the procedures at Waterloo, but some universities require direct transmission from the writer, not the candidate.

Whether they help or not depends on too many things, including the unknown future, to comment directly. But having the "on the shelf" is probably useful.

Comment: Actually yes, that's what my end goal is. that if for some reason, i couldn't get writers to update it, for any reason. I can explain my 2 year low performance in academics. and maybe at least, try to stand a chance, not just thrown out of consideration.